# Is there a way to dynamically add Omniauth providers/ strategy in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm planning to have an option in my web application to add more Omniauth providers / strategy without redeploying or restarting the web application.

I added a table where I can save the required values for the new strategy, then in *config/initializers/devise.rb* I iterated the values;

```rb
Devise.setup do |config|
  # AppConfigTable.oauth structure will be
  # "facebook"=>
  # [
  #  {
  #    id: 5,
  #    name: "key",
  #    value: "yyyyyyy",
  #   },
  #  {
  #   id: 6,
  #   name: "secret",
  #   value: "xxxxxxx"
  #  }
  # ]
  AppConfigTable.oauth&.each do |provider, oauth_values|
    data = oauth_values.map { |f| [f.name, f.value] }.to_h
    config.omniauth provider.to_sym,
                    data['key'],
                    data['secret']
  end
end
```

Now whenever I added a new strategy in my table, the new added strategy is not applied on the web application. I still need to restart the server to make it work.

## Update

> I moved the above code to a service that is called on every action. I still need to restart the server.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview - it's the official guide to how to add extra providers.

Comment: That's not the case Mark, I wanted to add it **DYNAMICALLY**.

Comment: **SORRY I SHOULD READ MORE CAREFULLY**

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I what to do the same, but with multiple Microsoft Graph as the provider.